# How to update fields from Select which contains Joins using ResultSet JDBC

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

Is it possible to update fields from many tables using ResultSet? 
I tried with the select:
"SELECT PERSONS.NAME FROM PERSONS " and it works
but when I have a join it throws an error saying that the field title is 
not valid.
Is it possible to write multiple joins and then update all fields or do 
I have to do it table by table?

Example code:

```
Statement statement = null;
try {
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    statement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
               ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String sql = "SELECT PERSONS.NAME, BOOKS.TITLE,* FROM PERSONS LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOKS ";
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

    while (rs.next()) {
        rs.updateString( "NAME", "John");
        rs.updateString("TITLE", "Random Title");
        rs.updateRow();
    }

} catch (SQLException e ) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
} finally {
    if (statement != null) { statement.close(); }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `LEFT JOIN`? You don't read or update the extra columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can remember, you can only update "simple" SQL `SELECT`s that correspond to a single table. When you add a join it suddenly becomes a "complex SQL".

Comment: I think you are write, I have not found anything else on the Internet. So how would you suggest that I execute update to many fields on different Tables? Just an update for every Table?

Comment: You don't really need to `SELECT` in order to update. Why don't you just run an `UPDATE`? What do you actually need?

Comment: I need to update fields from 3 different tables and I am wondering what is the best practice to do it.

Comment: I would recommend you ask another question and explain what you need to update. It sounds like a simple (well... maybe not that simple) update will do.